# Update a View state/data inside a item of a Recycler View list

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

looking for a solution to update the state of the view let's say a Button present in a Item of a Recycler View.
Example could be Facebook Suggested friend List where you send the request to a member, the button state changes from add friend to pending.

things i don't want to perform

1. complete data update of the RecyclerView
2. item update(so that image won't get flicked, when gets redrawn).

Comment: You can use DiffUtil is utility class that can calculate the difference between two lists and output a list of update operations that converts the first list into second one. It can be used to calculate updates for a RecyclerView Adapter.

Comment: But then the complete view holder will also get updated, right ? I want only certain view in the view holder to be updated.

Comment: No, it will not. If you have some changes it will trigger

onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int, payloads: MutableList<Any>) 

not  onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Partial changes with payloads](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter?hl=en) are the solution to this problem - that way you're not updating the entire item, avoiding the flickering.  [This article](https://medium.com/livefront/recyclerview-trick-selectively-bind-viewholders-with-payloads-4b28e3d2cce8) is a good explanation of this technique.